# Why do my OpenCV's GUI elements (trackbars, windows) have different design?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm building a Computarized Vision software. I've just started creating the user GUI, but the windows' design are very different from the ones I've seen in other OpenCV's softwares.

I've tried updating my OpenCV version, but the GUI design stills the same.

With my code I get this:

[image]

while the other GUIs I've seen look like this:

[image]

What do I have to do to change the design of my GUI?

Comment: The second print-screen looks like a _cv::imshow_ call in case OpenCV is built with _WITH_QT_ option (_highgui_ module uses Qt, the windows have extra features). But i'm not experienced enough with python to be able to help you set that up in python. It might be as simple as installing _PySide2_ package ( https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/contents.html ), or you might need to install a separate package for opencv (that is built with that option), or you might need to build it yourself and generate the python bindings yourself. Hope this helps, at least for you to know what to investigate next!

Comment: You're comparing two different operating systems. Qt uses native GUI widgets for each OS, so naturally they look different.